How can I merge similar rows in an SQL table ON specific condition in Partition By?
I need to perform a query in SQL, need to merge multiple flows which are similar. To check similarity I need to check if sourceIPAddress , destinationIPAddress, sourceTransportPort, destinationTransportPort are same and flowStartMilliseconds of next flow record is less than flowEndMiliseconds + (3600 x 1000) of the previous flow.  if these condition matches I need to merge those flows or rows like adding bytes column and packets column and put flowStartMilliseconds of first rows as flowStartMilliseconds and flowEndMiliseconds of last row as flowEndMiliseconds.
This is what I have done so far.
select 
  sourceIPAddress, 
  destinationIPAddress, 
  sourceTransportPort, 
  destinationTransportPort, 
  protocol, 
  serviceName, 
  flowStartMilliseconds, 
  flowEndMilliseconds, 
  row_number() over (
    partition by sourceIPAddress, 
    destinationIPAddress, 
    sourceTransportPort, 
    destinationTransportPort 
    order by 
      flowStartMilliseconds
  ) as row_num, 
  lag(flowEndMilliseconds) over (
    partition by sourceIPAddress, 
    destinationIPAddress, 
    sourceTransportPort, 
    destinationTransportPort 
    order by 
      flowStartMilliseconds
  ) as lag_value, 
  (lag_value + 3600 * 1000) as next_val, 
  case when flowStartMilliseconds < next_val then 1 else 0 end as condition, 
from 
  read_parquet(
    '//path/*/*/*/*/*/*.parquet', hive_partitioning = 1
  ) 
where 
  protocol = 'TCP';

I am using duckDB for this query.
Giving You same table here:

Like in this screen shot all the three rows should become one.

It would've been much easier to help you if you would've created simple example input and output. Adding images as examples does not help much.

As you don't have Minimal, Reproducible Example in your question, I've created a simple DataFrame which could illustrate the task, I'm using smaller numbers for easier reading, and 3 as a threshold distance between rows when we want to start new group
┌──────────┬───────┬─────┐
│ group_id ┆ start ┆ end │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ i64      ┆ i64   ┆ i64 │
╞══════════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ 1        ┆ 1     ┆ 5   │ # start of the continuous group 1
│ 1        ┆ 7     ┆ 8   │ # 7 < 5 + 3 => still in the group 1
│ 1        ┆ 10    ┆ 11  │ # 10 < 8 + 3 => still in the group 1
│ 1        ┆ 15    ┆ 16  │ # 15 >= 11 + 3 => start of the continuous group 2
│ 1        ┆ 20    ┆ 23  │ # 20 >= 16 + 3 => start of the continuous group 3
│ 1        ┆ 25    ┆ 30  │ # 25 < 23 + 3 => still in the group 3
│ 2        ┆ 2     ┆ 5   │ 
│ 2        ┆ 7     ┆ 10  │
└──────────┴───────┴─────┘


lag() to get previous row.
sum() to calculate group number.

with cte as (
    select
        d.group_id, d.start, d.end,
        lag(d.end) over (partition by d.group_id order by d.end) as lag_value,
        (lag_value + 3) as next_val,
        case when d.start >= next_val then 1 else 0 end as group_start
    from df as d
), cte2 as (
    select
        d.group_id, d.start, d.end,
        sum(d.group_start) over(partition by d.group_id order by d.start) as rle_id
    from cte as d
)
select
    d.group_id,
    min(d.start) as start,
    max(d.end) as end,
    count(*) as cnt_records
from cte2 as d
group by
    d.group_id,
    d.rle_id
order by
    d.group_id,
    min(d.start)

┌──────────┬───────┬─────┬─────────────┐
│ group_id ┆ start ┆ end ┆ cnt_records │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---         │
│ i64      ┆ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64         │
╞══════════╪═══════╪═════╪═════════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 1     ┆ 11  ┆ 3           │
│ 1        ┆ 15    ┆ 16  ┆ 1           │
│ 1        ┆ 20    ┆ 30  ┆ 2           │
│ 2        ┆ 2     ┆ 10  ┆ 2           │
└──────────┴───────┴─────┴─────────────┘

